# Add to cart process

Tags: php, mysql, cart, inventory

```
 foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
  $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
  $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM prod WHERE              
  id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

      $price = $row["prod_price"]; 
      $stocks = $row["stocks"];
}

 $sqlu = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE prod SET stocks = $stocks
   WHERE id =  'item_id'");     


 }
```

Im planning to create an inventory system but I failed mostly . When I add lot of items in the cart I can only update the last record. Im planning to update all of the items I added in the cart

for instances I add 5 products lets say for example 20 X apple , 10 X banana, 10 X grapes, 40 X sugar, 60 X oranges. I want to update the stocks with these 5 items not just the last item I added which is oranges ..

Here's the download link of the system that Im using as a reference. It has an add to cart function but no checkout and it doesnt have an inventory system. please help me

http://www.developphp.com/ExampleSites/Ecommerce_Series_Source/MyOnlineStore.zip

Im trying to store the data in array but no luck the key always stuck with [0]

Answer (score 0):

What is the delimiter for $_SESSION["cart_array"]?

I think that you simply need to convert it from a string into an object or array so foreach can iterate all of the items in the collection.

> foreach (explode("**YOUR-DELIMITER**", $_SESSION["cart_array"]) as $each_item)

Comment: hello ? are you there ? do you have facebook? I want to contact you and ask some questions